# CentOS 8 Back to Windows 11

Tags: centos

So long story short - I botched a CentOS update from 7 to 8 and now I am unable to use most functions on the server. I will have to go back to CentOS 7 to get these features to work again.

I am trying to backup my files/folders from CentOS so that I don't lose all the web sites and data that has been collected.

I have been trying to find a way to setup rsync on Windows, and connect CentOS to Windows using rsync but I have had no luck being able to connect to it.

I am using a Virtual Machine Windows 11 to try and back up to, so there's no firewall / security on it.

I honestly do not know if rsync is even the way to go, I was looking at dump as well but read that's old and not as good..

please advise.

Comment: Why not just use a USB drive to backup the data?  Simple is sometimes the best solution

Comment: What messages/errors do you get when you try rsync? What did you actually try? What is your VM's network config? What research have you done regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by using Putty + pscp on Windows with the command:

```
pscp - P 22 username@host.com:/public_html/backup.tar c:\users\public\dl
```